# Changing opacity between lines in a vector layer

Tags: qgis, vector-layer

The extent of my knowledge with QGIS is how to join up layers and apply data.

I have a vector layer of MSOA's for 2021 taken from [ONS Geography](https://geoportal.statistics.gov.uk/datasets/ons::middle-layer-super-output-areas-2021-boundaries-ew-bfc/explore) on boundaries for England and Wales, I wish when using graduated symbology (using a delimited text layer for data) to reduce the black line borders between MSOA's, so that the lines between areas looks less pronounced, it currently looks like [this](https://imgur.com/a/xF83L01) zoomed out.

My objective is to make my maps into something similar akin to this [here](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Christianity_Greater_London_2011_census.png) on Wikipedia (example is with 2011 shapefile), if this is something which can be done on QGIS.

Comment: have you tried setting the border colour to the same as the fill colour?

Comment: Set the Opacity of the Stroke Color to 0%?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately, you will need to pay attention to the "stroke style" setting in the Symbology.
If you want to achieve the Wikipedia-like look, you will need to make the following steps:

- color in the polygons based on a variable that will give you that "graduated" symbol look. (if you don't have something to fill the polygons, and take out the stroke, you will look at a white screen)
- right-click on your chosen layer in the "Layers" list >> choose "Properties" from the menu >> choose "Symbology"
- choose the "Graduated color" option and select the field you wish to display. (For starters, even the "shape area" will do.)
- choose a color and initiate classification. (This will provide that varied "Fill" that you see on that blue gradient map.)

2. Once you have the "Fill", you can work on eliminating the polygon boundary lines:

- left-click on the fill color/"Symbol" color bar >> it will open up a smaller window ("Symbol settings")
- left-click on "Simple fill" >> it will pull new options into the window
- look for "Stroke style". In your version, it will be set to "Solid Line", but you will see many options when you click on it.
- if you want to eliminate it entirely, choose "No Pen"
- alternatively, you can make it transparent by clicking on the arrow button at the "Stroke color" bar and check the "Transparent stroke" in the new pop-up window
- however, you can also play with the color, opacity, width and more. Depending on the effect and information you want to display, you might want to just soften the color but keep showing the boundaries to indicate the separation between the areas that have similar/same fill color.
- once you have the desired "stroke style", click OK, then, OK again on the "Properties" window and it should set your styles